# Xcode IB auto sizing?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

Everything looks fine in IB.  When I run my app using an iPhone5/iPhone6/iPad sims, it's completely mangled.

In IB:

[image]

In iPhone6 sim:

[image]

In the above sim, the buttons are cut. The textfield and textview are also cut.  For the TF & TV, they are aligned center but trail off the edges on both sides.

I have the buttons width set

> Editor > Pin > Widths  Equally

The title label is set with a

> Horizontal Center in Container

constraint

The textfield and textview also have

> Horizontal Center in Container

and

> Editor > Pin > Width

Is there some way to fix this?

-- EDIT --

After a few tries with constraints, looks like I have everything working except the two buttons.

[image]

Current listing of constraints:

[image]

Comment: Use Autolayout feature of Xcode. [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial)

Comment: That would require a significant amount of work.  The first thing I did when I created this project was turn auto layout off.  All of my scenes were iPhone shaped.  It looked fine in the iOS simulator just a few hours ago.  I'm not sure what happened.

Comment: I think since I started added background colors, I can see a problem that was probably always there.  But for whatever reason, XB seems to default to iPhone 5 sizes.

Comment: Have you used 'Size inspector' for Autolayout property?

Comment: @the_UB: Yes.  For the most part, that seems to make scenes look fine on the iPhone6 sim.  But for one scene, I have two buttons side by side at the bottom of a view.  When I run them in the sim, one button's width is resized so wide, it goes out of view.

Comment: If you build most of your UI in Interface Builder, then I'd really suggest you take the Autolayout route. It is not that much work usually (it might just look daunting at first). We are happy to help if you have trouble with it. Autolayout is specifically designed to make your life easier when there are different screen sizes (an nowadays there usually are)

Comment: I'm using auto layouts and have updated the question with new info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by others, you should consider using the Auto-layout feature if you plan on constructing your views using the IB.

Here are some tutorial links:

[RayWenderlich.com Part One](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng) This one covers a bit of size clases

Hope they help.

**UPDATED:**

I've read your updated post, you need to add width and height constraints. The view you see in the IB right now is 600 by 600 points, and the simulator one is smaller, which means that if you leave it as is, when you run the app you'll only see what the iphone screen has the capacity to show.

You need to add more constraints than what you used, try defining an equal width for the buttons, and assign the left one a left margin constraint, the right one a right margin constraint, give both of them vertical spacing constraint related to the text view or long label, the text view or long label should have left and right margin constraints, a height constraint and a top constraint to the textfield, the textfield should have a vertical spacing constraint to the label, also left and right and height constraint, and last the label should have leff, right and height constraints plus a top constraint to the main view.

I feel that those are all you need, but Xcode will through warnings at you if it feels you are missing something.

Try it, and let us know.

Comment: I've tried it with auto layout as well.  Looks great in IB but then totally mangled once I head to the sims.

Comment: I've added a new update to list the constraints I'm using.  It seems to be just the buttons that are giving me issues.  I do have width constraints on both.  Where is the margin constraint you mentioned?

Comment: The buttons should not have a fixed width, remove that, select them both add equal widths constraint and a horizontal spacing constraint with a constant of 0

Comment: Ok.  Removed width and added equal widths.  Where do I find the horizontal spacing constraint?

Comment: left click and drag from one button to the other, and from the pop menu select horizontal spacing

Comment: I'll give it a try once Xcode stops crashing.  Now it is constantly crashing so there isn't much I can do.

Comment: I have the spacing set as you described and the buttons have equal width.  However, they are small and pushed flush left.  Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I just replaced the last couple of pics with updates that show the current constraints.  What's weird, even if I Editor > Pin > Width at 300 on one of the buttons, it completely ignores it.  No effect on the UI.

Comment: From what I can see, you have some warnings, the red and yellow lines indicate that. That means that you are missing something or misplaced a constraint.

Comment: It's like an endless rabbit hole with this thing.  Fix one thing and it breaks another.  No way out.

Comment: I know, sometimes Auto-layout can be a pain, it's a matter of practice, practice and more practice. You'll get the hang of it eventually. I really suggest following some tutorials and simpler stuff, and then come back to this. Also check Size Classes while you are at it.